# Testing WSDL Web Service

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I have a bunch of WSDL web service link with me. I need to write automation code to test this service. 
What library you all recommended (Spring, or others). Any reference website would be good. Thanks.

Comment: Not clear... do you provide or consume the web services ? You want to test an external app or the app you are building ?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to create Spring Boot projects and use Apache CXF dependencies and plugins, It is simple and efficient both.
All you need is to follow some steps :

1) Copy the WSDL into your project.

2) Add `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws` and `cxf-codegen-plugin` dependencies.

3) Include plugin that contains the path of your WSDL file.

4) Create a `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean` client and access your webservice.

You can take some reference from here https://dzone.com/articles/soap-web-services-with-apache-cxf-and-spring-boot

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score 0):

[SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/getting-started/) has been around for years. I've used it to integrate and test projects even while not working in Java. It generates client side code based on the WSDL definition and also test code (including functional, load and security tests).

Comment: Im looking for test automation library n not test web service tools.

Comment: Direct link: https://www.soapui.org/professional/soapui-pro/features/automated-api-testing/

Comment: if you are interested in test automation library then there are many questions and answers that reference this

Answer (score 0):

I'm out of this domain several years. But it seems that WSO2 still provides Enterprise Integration and related products, check Whether it is relevant at their doc about [Publishing a Custom WSDL](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Publishing+a+Custom+WSDL) or their [Test Automation Framework](https://docs.wso2.com/display/TA430/Introducing+Test+Automation+Framework)